# Odd Acceptance Ratio

Tags: prior, metropolis-hastings

Recently, I read some paper and sometimes they draw a sample $s\sim N(a,b)\times exp(d)$. But they defined the prior as $N(A,b) \times exp(D)$ with unknown $A$ and $D$. Therefore in the acceptance ratio $N(A,b) \times exp(D)$ appears.

While others just sample from $s\sim N(a,b)$ while the prior was defined as $N(A,b)\times exp(D)$. Again with unknown $A$ and $D$.

Makes all that sense?

Answer (score 1):

In the second, if D is unkown, then it should be sampled for. I'd suggest looking through the paper again and seeing what they do to find D.

Two potential reasons why it might not appear in an acceptance ratio are:

1. Some kind of Gibbs / blocking scheme / Metropolis-within-Gibbs is being employed. Under which there would be two or more blocks of variables sampled and $D$ would be assumed known in one of them. (If sampling for $D$ is pure Gibbs, there would be no acceptance ratio.)
2. $D$ is being optimised out rather than sampled for in some kind of hybrid method.

Not exhaustive, but may give you some ideas to start with.